# ASP.NET Web API 2 override inherited attribute route action multiple actions found

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, overriding, attributerouting

To keep an overview in my Web API, I am using a base controller that contains some basic actions that most of my other controllers use. (E.g. `Post([FromBody]JObject newFields)` to add a new item.)

In my project, I have attribute routing enabled. So my base controller looks somewhat like the following:

```
public class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T : ObjectBase, new()
{
    [Route("")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ObjectBase))]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject newFields)
    {
        // Post logic
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I am inheriting this base controller in most of the other controllers in my project.

**Now for my problem:**

In one of my controllers, I want to override this method, because some of the creation logic is different.

This is an example of how I am trying to accomplish that functionality:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : BaseController<UserObject>
{
    [Route("")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ObjectBase))]
    public override IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject newFields)
    {
        // Overridden post logic
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

However, when I now send a `POST` request to `https://url/api/Users`, I get the following error response:

> Message:
>
> > An error has occurred.
>
> ExceptionMessage:
>
> > Multiple actions were found that match the request:
> >
> > Post on type WebAPI.Controllers.UsersController
> >
> > Post on type WebAPI.Controllers.UsersController
>
> ExceptionType:
>
> > System.InvalidOperationException
>
> StackTrace:
>
> > at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
> >
> > at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> >
> > at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

Anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, I finally found a most simple solution.
Seems like I just had to remove the attributes in my derived class.

So to follow the example I used in my original post, the `UsersController` now looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : BaseController<UserObject>
{
    public override IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject newFields)
    {
        // Overridden post logic
        return Ok();
    }
}
```